# Javascript 'else' vs 'is not true'

Tags: javascript

In theory, what would be faster:

```
if(condition !== 0)
{
    //action #1
}
else
{
    //action #2
}
```

OR

```
if(condition == 0)
{
    //action #2
}
else
{
    //action #1
}
```

Keep in mind that the condition is much more likely (around 10x) to NOT be zero, so action #1 is much more likely to be executed. 
It basically comes down to which is slower:
requesting an else statement or looking if the condition is NOT true (as opposed to if it were true). Thanks.

Comment: If there is any difference, it would be nanoscopic.

Comment: You could use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) to find out, but like @NiettheDarkAbsol says, I doubt you'd see a difference.

Comment: If there's a difference, and that difference is important for you, then you probably shouldn't rely on javascript. There are so many things that could slow down execution client side, that kind of optimization seems, to me, a lost of time. That said I tend to prefer putting the more likely cases in the `if` clause.

Comment: FYI: `(==) != !(!==)`

Comment: @Andy I already made a test there was, as expected, virtualy no difference. Still, I would like a more detailed answer than 'it does not matter'.

Comment: @Bartdude Nothing is lost time if it leads to a deeper understanding of something. As implied in the original post, I'm not trying to optimize, but to understand.

Comment: @user, one being *very slightly* faster or slower than the other would depend on your specific Javascript interpreter/jitter, most probably your operating system, and quite possibly the hardware you're running it on. I'm afraid there is no general answer to that question.

Comment: I think you should then search for tools measuring Javascript performance and perform tests yourself on a very large scale to see a difference if there's any. That won't affect your understunding though, only your knowledge : you'll know which is faster, not why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single `if-else` block of code, it doesn't matter. Here's why:

- When your condition in the `if` statement is interpreted, the interpreter will store it in memory as a boolean - `true` or `false`. **This always happens no matter what.**
- The interpreter naturally sets up two "go-to" points that branch from your `if` statement's evaluation. Since your condition is already evaluated, the interpreter is now thinking, "If the condition is `true`, I'll do `{something}`. But if it's false, I'll do `{something else}`." In other words, the interpreter will "jump" to one of two places in your code, but it has already defined what happens in either case.

If you had `else-if` statements as well, this *would* impact performance since if the first `if` condition isn't true, it must evaluate *another* one. However, in your example this is not the case, so they will take the same time either way.

I'm obligated to say this: it is **highly** recommended to use `===` instead of `==`. Here's a [JavaScript equality table](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) that shows how the different equals conversions are handled.

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling tells me this is negligible. In compiled languages this might make a difference because of pipelining / branch prediction. If those are the kinds of optimizations you're looking for then JavaScript is not the right language for you.

Using `==` instead of `===` (or `!==`) might have a considerable impact though.

Comment: I understand there is no practical value in this. That is why I explicitly said 'in theory'. I am just wondering what this 'nano' effect is.

Comment: I actually ran a jsperf out of curiosity on the subject of `==` vs. `===` when the type is known to be the same (for instance, `"a".charCodeAt(0) == 65` vs. `=== 65`) and found that there was literally no difference - it's possible that `==` is implemented first by checking type, then casting if they are different, then checking value - in the case of known same type, that would make it identical to `===`'s behaviour.

Comment: *"In compiled languages this might make a difference..."* JavaScript is frequently compiled these days. V8 (the engine in Chrome and NodeJS) is an optimizing two-stage JIT compiler, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you mixed up the conditions. #1 uses the identity operator which neglects type-casting. The #2 will use type-casting if `condition` is non-integer.

In theory the #2 will be slower, due to the type-casting/converting.

However, if you'd change the #2 to identity `===` it would be more or less the same. The only difference between `!==` and `===` is one additional operation, to convert `false` to `true`, which is faster than speed of light.

I'd suggest using the identity operator if you can ensure the data-types are the same. [Take a look at this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/identity-vs-equality-of-same-type) for convincing. It is more than 100% faster.